# Using jQuery mobile touchmove. CSS transition not behaving as wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I can start of by saying that my intended target is mobile browsers and showing what I'm trying to do here, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/batcave/Lufznen8/6/) (a div goes to the right corner with the help of css transition).

So as you can see it works fine with `scroll` and in a regular browser. Trying this in a mobile emulation with Chrome Canary works fine. Taking this to mobile won't work as expected. The `transition` will happen once you stop "scrolling". Now I tried jQuery Mobiles `scrollstart`, but that is essentially the same behvaiour as `scroll`.
 I searched the issue and came across `touchmove`. Fair enough it actually logs each step of the "scrolling", so I got that pinned down. Now this bring another issue, the `transition` won't work. What happens is that it will position in the corner right away and "keeping a instance" of the `widget__status` in it's original position.

I would highly appreciate help on this one. 

here is the code used in the fiddle demo

```
<div class="widget">
    <div class="widget__start clearfix">
        <div class="widget__status"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="widget__body"></div>
```

jQuery

```
var body = $('body');

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.scrollTop() == 0) {
        body.removeClass('fixed');
    } else {
        if (!body.hasClass('fixed')) {
            body.addClass('fixed');
        }
    }
});
```

Relevant css

```
.widget__status {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: #333;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s, right 1s;
}

.fixed .widget__status {
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I use jQuery mobile for my solution why wouldn't it be a relevant tag?

Comment: Transition will fire once events are emitted. However, using touch events, you have full control. For instance, you can trigger transition when user moves from x to y.

Comment: @Omar can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: `scrollstart` and `scrollstop` are custom events. Those events are emitted when user starts/stops scrolling. Hence, you should wait for them to be triggered. If you want to do something "during" scrolling, you'll need to modify the way they behave.

Comment: @Omar Can you give me an example of how to modify `scrollstart`event?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/0920b15801ff59066f7272d8ddcea7603821d437/js/events/touch.js this link contains JQM special events.

Comment: @Omar i used the touchmove and it register during scroll. I cant see how this link will help me? My issue now is the transition not behaving as expexted using touchmove

Comment: Now you want to use JQM or touch events? Come to chat